# Angular: Hightlight animation on table rows

Tags: css, angular, typescript

### Situation

I have a table with devices and their statuses. When I click on a specific button the rows that have the offline status need to have a highlight for a couple of seconds and then return back to normal.

### What I have so far

```
<tr id="deviceRow" class="user-item" *ngFor="let device of group.devices" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" [class.highlightOn]="this.offlineHighlight == true && device.onlineState == 'Offline'">
```

When I click on the button the offlineHighlight boolean becomes true and it adds the highlightOn class which is this.

```
.highlightOn {
  background-color: rgb(255, 68, 65);
  -webkit-animation: fade-out 3s ease-out both;
  animation: fade-out 3s ease-out both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade-out {
  0% {
    background-color: rgba(255,51,47,1);
  }
  100% {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}
@keyframes fade-out {
  0% {
    background-color: rgba(255,51,47,1);
  }
  100% {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

This adds the 'highlight' animation.

After the animation is completed I set the offlineHighlught boolean to false again in the button code.

```
  showOfflineDevices() {
    this.offlineHighlight = true;
    this.tabIndex = 1;
    setTimeout(function(){
      this.offlineHighlight = false;
    }, 3000);
  }
```

It all works fine until the animation has completed. Standard the table rows have different background colors for each odd even row. When the animation is complete all the rows that had the highlightOn class have a white background color as you can see here.

[image]
[image]

[image]

**TL:DR The background color of the table rows need to go back to normal after the animation is completed. The even rows are also white now, which need to be grey.**

Comment: I don't have access to images (corporate proxy), could you please make a [mcve] ? (By the way, thank you for the TL;DR, this should be a requirement to post a new question)

Comment: @trichetriche I'm sorry, but I don't think I can make it more minimal. The button calls the showOfflineDevices() function which sets the boolean to true. It then adds the highlightsOn class to the row which animates for 3 seconds. Then the timer in the button function sets the boolean back to false.

Comment: You're right about minimal, but it was more about the verifiable part. You know, something we can play with ?

Comment: @trichetriche Uhm I'm not sure man, I'll try if you really need it, but it's the first time I've done that so not sure how long it's going to take.

Comment: Well I'm not the one having an issue :P you can use stackblitz, it dhould take about 10 minutes if you followed the style guide given by angular. But I see you have an answer, so don't bother !

Answer (score 0):

It's because you set `background-color` to `transparent` on `fade-out`, you can simply use `transitions` like this (just add and remove class with additional styles, don't override existing styles on `fade-out`):

```js
setInterval(() => {
  $(".color").addClass("selected");
  setTimeout(() => {
    $(".color").removeClass("selected")
  }, 2500);
}, 5000);
```

```css
div {
  transition: background-color .5s ease;
}

div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

div:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: gray;
}

.selected {
  background-color: green !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>1</div>
<div class="color">2</div>
<div class="color">3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
```

Comment: I'm looking into it now, will report back when I have any troubles.... Or it might just work first time haha.